# Gitlab-runner docker container is using the Gitlab container_id as the clone url

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to configure a simple Gitlab-ci build pipeline and am running all of the components in docker containers. I followed the general guides on docs.gitlab.com and got a runner registered with gitlab. But when a build kicks off, the runner tries to clone the repository in question and seems to use the gitlab instance's container-id in place of the url, and I get an unreachable-host error:

```
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/root/ci-demo'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@cdfd596f2bc4/root/ci-demo.git/': Could not resolve host: cdfd596f2bc4
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Is there something obvious that I've overlooked? There are quite a few similar questions on SO and the internet in general, but none seem to have a problem with the target container-id being substituted for the url.

gitlab-runner's config.toml:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "runner_name"
  url = "http://[ipaddr]:[port]/"
  token = "xxxxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "maven:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

Comment: I would consider posting this on devops.stackexchange.com or serverfault.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have same problem