# Self-Hosted Gitlab Pipeline CI job throws error 403

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

im new in gitlab and i am trying to set up my self hosted gitlab-ce docker container on ubuntu vps to practice with. what i did till now is >> setup gitlab container and its behind nginx with url of git.domain.com (https by certbot). >> setup the gitlab-runner container >> added the runner to a test project.
i have a test project that contains REDME.md and .gitlab-ci.yml files only.
my .gitlab-ci.yml is very simple:

```
image: docker:latest


before_script:  
  - echo "Hello, yoo"
  - echo "Hello, yoo"


stages:
    - build
    - test
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "building.....!"
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - build/
test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing....!"
```

whenever the CI pipeline triggered it throws error in build step.

```
> Running with gitlab-runner 15.8.0 (12335144)   on test-docker-runner
> 7PpT2V-e, system ID: r_tGxvS4HIDNWl Preparing the "docker" executor
> 00:04 Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ... Pulling
> docker image docker:latest ... Using docker image
> sha256:cd27a71ea4555b89fda3a6fd0118200e247b9f05cd07d3c16c58e67bee7c290d
> for docker:latest with digest
> docker@sha256:3cf33ff6e893a39262bd9f6b85ff46e068fa2a98d201326e9c3058a22a21a6bb
> ... Preparing environment 00:00 Running on
> runner-7ppt2v-e-project-2-concurrent-0 via 468dc8b24685... Getting
> source from Git repository 00:02 Fetching changes with git depth set
> to 20... Reinitialized existing Git repository in
> /builds/gitlab-instance-91dbc115/test/.git/ fatal: unable to access
> 'http://3fd88525ccde/gitlab-instance-91dbc115/test.git/': The
> requested URL returned error: 403 Cleaning up project directory and
> file based variables 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

i have tried different instructions like add member (i created another admin acc) and tried with that account but still get the same error.
also change the project from private to internal and yet getting the error.

another thing is when i want clone to my local machine (clone with http) it throws

> fatal: unable to access
> 'http://3fd88525ccde/gitlab-instance-91dbc115/test.git/': Could not
> resolve host: 3fd88525ccde

but if i change url to https://git.domain.com/gitlab-instance-91dbc115/test.git/ then it works.

**UPDATE:** it seems the 3fd88525ccde is the Container ID of gitlab-ce.
[Same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546102/gitlab-runner-docker-container-is-using-the-gitlab-container-id-as-the-clone-url)

**UPDATE:** i modified the docker-copose and add hostname= "git.domain.com" to gitlab service and then the problem of urlin my repository solved but my runner stops working. i tried to add it fresh to project by command > docker-runner register inside the runner container but it does not accept the https://git.domain.com as url with connection refused error. [check similar issue](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/connectivity-issues-between-gitlab-runner-and-gitlab-in-a-docker-environment/49555)

Comment: Because you use docker executor your build happen inside container that does not know about that DNS (3fd88525ccde). What you can do is pass information to /etc/hosts inside to your build container via config.toml (when configuring your runner) like this: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#adding-extra-host-aliases

Comment: thank you, just now i modified my docker-compose and add hostname="git.domain.com" to gitlab-ce service and now the git url is fixed in repository however now i face my runner is offline :D.